# Angular-breadcrumb: label/parent relationship

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ncybreadcrumb

I am trying to use ncy-breadcrumb in my application but I don't know how to solve one particular case.

First of all I have these 2 states:

```
{
          state: 'installation-edit',
          config: {
              abstract: true,
              url: '/installation-edit/{installationId}',
              templateUrl: 'app/installation/edit/installation.edit.html',
              controller: 'InstallationEditController',
              title: 'installation.edit.tab.title'
          }
      },
      {
          state: 'installation-edit.detail',
          config: {
              url: '',
              views: {
                  'maindata': {
                      templateUrl: 'app/installation/edit/installation.edit.main.data.html',
                      controller: 'InstallationEditMainDataController',
                      controllerAs: 'vmInstMainData'
                  },
                  'equipments': {
                      templateUrl: 'app/installation/edit/installation.edit.equipments.html',
                      controller: 'InstallationEditEquipmentsController',
                      controllerAs: 'vmInstEquipments'
                  },
                  'users': {
                      templateUrl: 'app/installation/edit/installation.edit.users.html',
                      controller: 'InstallationEditUsersController',
                      controllerAs: 'vmInstUsers'
                  }
              },
              ncyBreadcrumb: {
                  label: '{{installationName}}'
              }
          }
      }
```

The `installationName` variable is defined in the `InstallationEditController` to the appropriate value, something like this:

```
function activate() {

InstallationEditMainDataService.getInstallationMainData($stateParams.installationId)
                .then(
                        function(response) {
                            $scope.installationName = response.data.name;
                        }
                );
        }
```

At this point everything is working perfectly fine. Let's say **MY-INSTALLATION** is shown in my HTML

Now I have a new state I want to be a child state from the previous one, but this is not a real parent/child relationship in the angular-ui-router configuration, so I use the parent property. This state is defined like this:

```
state: 'equipment-general-view',
        config: {
          url: '/equipment-general-view/{equipmentId}',
          templateUrl: 'app/equipment/general-view/general.view.html',
          controller: 'EquipmentGeneralViewController',
          controllerAs: 'vmEquipmentGeneralView',
          title: 'equipment.general.view.tab.title',
          ncyBreadcrumb: {
              label: '{{equipmentName}}',
              parent: 'installation-edit.detail({installationId: 128032})'
          }
        }
```

At this point, `equipmentName` is resolved correctly in  `EquipmentGeneralViewController` by following the same process as the previous case. Let's say that `equipmentName` is resolved to **MY-EQUIPMENT**

The idea is that ncy-breadcrumb displays the following: **MY-INSTALLATION /  MY-EQUIPMENT** but `intallationName` is not resolved at this point so only **/  MY-EQUIPMENT** is displayed.

I know what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it. In this case `intallationName` is not resolved because `InstallationEditController` is not executed at this moment, so `intallationName` is empty.

How can I pass the value of `intallationName` from the child state?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using $rootScope instead of $scope to set those special breadcrumb variables:

```
$rootScope.installationName = response.data.name;
```